# Django view works fine in browser, returns 500 when fetched by Backbone

Tags: javascript, python, django, backbone.js

I have a Django view which returns JSON formatted settings configuration file. It works fine when I GET it in the browser. But when I try to fetch the Backbone Collection that's linked to it, it returns a 500 with this error message : "'list' object has no attribute 'find'".

Stacktrace:

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/ConfigParser.py in _interpolate_some
    _interpvar_re = re.compile(r"%\(([^)]+)\)s")
    def _interpolate_some(self, option, accum, rest, section, map, depth):
        if depth > MAX_INTERPOLATION_DEPTH:
            raise InterpolationDepthError(option, section, rest)
        while rest:
            p = rest.find("%")  <-- where the stacktrace leads to
            if p < 0:
                accum.append(rest)
                return
            if p > 0:
                accum.append(rest[:p])
                rest = rest[p:]
```

The headless configuration reader:

```
class SectionlessConfig():
    def __init__(self, fp):
        self.fp = fp
        self.sechead = "[root]\n"

    def readline(self):
        if self.sechead:
            try:
                return self.sechead
            finally:
                self.sechead = None
        else:
            return self.fp.readline()

class Settings():
    configuration_file=settings.SHAKEARRAY_CFG_PATH

    def __init__(self):
        self.parser = ConfigParser.SafeConfigParser()

    def get_all_settings(self):
        self.parser.readfp(SectionlessConfig(open(Settings.configuration_file)))

        return self.parser.items('root')
```

The Django view code:

```
def all_settings(request):
    settings_list = seiscomp_settings.get_all_settings()
    settings_array = []

    for name, value in settings_list:
        settings_obj = {}
        settings_obj['name'] = name
        settings_obj['value'] = value
        settings_array.append(settings_obj)

    return JsonResponse(settings_array, safe=False)
```

I'm not sure whether the Backbone code will be of much assistance, but here is it nonetheless.

```
'use strict';

Shakescreen.module('Settings', function(Settings, App, Backbone) {
    Settings.Setting = Backbone.Model.extend({
        urlRoot: 'http://localhost:8000/settings',
        idAttribute: 'name',

        initialize: function() {
            console.log('creating setting object');
        }
    });

    Settings.SettingsCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        url: 'http://localhost:8000/settings',
        model: Settings.Setting,

        initialize: function() {
            console.log('initialize empy settings collection');
        }
    });
});
```

So the fetch on the SettingsCollection returns a 500, but a GET through the browsers works just fine (wget for that matter too). Any tips?

Comment: Is the code taking a different path due to different `content-type` headers in your request?

Comment: Stacktrace shows it originates from the same view. I thought it might have something to do with CORS, but other requests are getting through just fine.

Comment: If it is a CORS rejection, the _browser_ won't _accept_ the response, but the server will still send the response.  I suggest installing [WinPDB](http://winpdb.org/docs/embedded-debugging/) and then creating a remote debugging instance: `import rpdb2; rpdb2.start_embedded_debugger('foo')`.  Then, in WinPDB you'll be able to remotely attach to the server when you send the failing request.

Comment: I'll have to try that out when I've got some extra time on my hands, thanks. For the time being I've switched out SafeConfigParser for the old ConfigParser. Not really an answer to the question or an ideal solution, but it works.